# How to decode JSON in ElasticSearch load pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, aws-elasticsearch

I set up ElasticSearch on AWS and I am trying to load application log into it. The twist is that application log entry is in JSON format, like

> {"EventType":"MVC:GET:example:6741/Common/GetIdleTimeOut","StartDate":"2021-03-01T20:46:06.1207053Z","EndDate":"2021-03-01","Duration":5,"Action":{"TraceId":"80001266-0000-ac00-b63f-84710c7967bb","HttpMethod":"GET","FormVariables":null,"UserName":"ZZZTHMXXN"} ...}

So, I am trying to unwrap it. Filebeat [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filtering-and-enhancing-data.html) suggest that there is `decode_json_fields` processor; however, I am getting message fields in Kinbana as a single JSON string; nothing unwrapped.

I am new to ElasticSearch, but I am not going to use it as an excuse not to do analysis first. Only as an explanation that I am not sure which information is helpful for answering the question.

Here is `filebeat.yml`:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/opt/logs/**/*.json
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
    when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
  - decode_json_fields:
    fields: ["message"]

output.logstash:
    hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

And here is Logstash configuration file:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["https://search-blah-blah.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:443"]
        ssl => true
        user => "user"
        password => "password"
        index => "my-logs"
        ilm_enabled => false
    }
}
```

I am still trying to understand the filtering and grok parts of `Logstash`, but it *seems* that it should work the way it is. Also, I am not sure where the actual tag *messages* comes from (probably, from Logstash or Filebeat), but it seems irrelevant as well.

**UPDATE**: AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-logstash.html) doesn't give an example of just loading through filebeat, without logstash.
If I don't use logstash (just FileBeat) and have the following section in filebeat.yml:

```
output.elasticsearch:
    hosts: ["https://search-bla-bla.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:443"]

    protocol: "https"
    #index: "mylogs"

    # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
    #api_key: "id:api_key"
    username: "username"
    password: "password"
```

I am getting the following errors:
If I use `index: "mylogs"` - setup.template.name and setup.template.pattern have to be set if index name is modified

And if I don't use index (where would it go in ES then?) -

> Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(https://search-bla-bla.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:443)): Connection marked as failed because the onConnect callback failed: cannot retrieve the elasticsearch license from the /_license endpoint, Filebeat requires the default distribution of Elasticsearch. Please make the endpoint accessible to Filebeat so it can verify the license.: unauthorized access, could not connect to the xpack endpoint, verify your credentials

Comment: The indenting in your Filebeat configuration doesn't seem correct. Also, why do you need Logstash (if you're not applying any filters it's useless to you), why don't you send your data directly from Filebeat to Elasticsearch?

Comment: Also filebeat misses an output section in the sample yml provided

Comment: @AydinK. - I added the section from filebeat.yml. Sorry. Val - I fixed indentation (it was from copying to SO) and I added the errors if I only use filebeat without logstash. *With* logstash the problem seemed easier - everything got loaded, just not parsed. without logstash the problem looks much more complicated ;)

Comment: I wonder if your yml has correct format https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/decode-json-fields.html

Comment: Felix, if transmitting via logstash works in general, add a filter block as Val proposed and use this json plugin/filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html - it automatically parses the json into elasticsearch fields

Comment: @AydinK. - do you want to put your comment as answer, so I can accept it? I am still trying to figure it out... this is the plugin to Logstash, rather than filebeat, right?

Comment: @AydinK. - it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @HùngPhạmViệt - sorry, it was the problem when pasting in SO. updated the question

Comment: @Felix: Welcome. Done :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If transmitting via logstash works in general, add a filter block as Val proposed in the comments and use this json plugin/filter: elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html - it automatically parses the json into elasticsearch fields